# VS2012 ClickOnce Applications not working on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, clickonce, visual-studio-2012

While installing on WinXP ,following error apperad
[image: error message]

On Win7 application installed without problem.
Windows forms app and WPF app both have the same problem and both of them worked correctly before in VS 2010.

Comment: Is it a Windows desktop or "metro" application? Did you target Any CPU or just 64 bit OS?

Comment: Not a metro one.One is Winform and second is WPF.Both of them were working before in VS2010.I noticed that setup.exe changed in new version.In Windows 7 application installs without problem.

Comment: You should include this (and any other relevant information) in your question.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. The exact same project published within VS 2012 won't install on windows XP. It is a standard WPF application which when publish within VS2010 works perfectly.

Comment: So I hope that VS2012 project will work on VS2010 SP1 ,so I have to use virtual pc to publish my project.

Comment: Check on project properties - publish - prerequsites if any of them has warning. I had this case where windows installer was not found in vs2012.

Comment: Windows XP: tick, tick, tick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way is to publish it from VS 2010 SP1.Projects are compatible in both studios.

Comment: I was able to use this technique until we were forced into upgrading ReportViewer to 2012, which doesn't work with VS'10.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, but found a simple fix:
Instead of running the setup.exe run the "xxxxxx.application" (manifest) file in the same location.
This will execute and install in exactly the same manner and does not complain about not being a 32bit app.

Comment: Isn't the setup.exe required to install the .net frameworks if they are  missing from client machine?

Comment: This won't work because the .application file won't install dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.Please see: [Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/10/15/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx). And also: [Visual Studio Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1-now-available.aspx)

Comment: Related:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-