# Windows Forms project under VS2012 not installable on Win XP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I target .NET 4.0.3 on XP using Visual Studio 2012? Application fails to run with “not a valid Win32 application”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319952/how-do-i-target-net-4-0-3-on-xp-using-visual-studio-2012-application-fails-to)

I use Visual Studio 2012 to develop my windows forms projects. I am able to produce ClickOnce setup files to install on Win 7/8 OS but I am not able to install it on Win XP.

Error message is **setup.exe is not a valid win32 application**.

I know this OS is (officially) no more supported with VS2012. I know the will be a fix latier in 2012 to correct it. But maybe there is a solution to allow me to install my Windows Forms project on Win XP?

Thanks.

PS: I read this [VS2012 ClickOnce Applications not working on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508697/vs2012-clickonce-applications-not-working-on-windows-xp) but not solution has been suggested (except working with VS2010).

I also read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/dd3eec8c-93b0-4243-9419-233f20b257d4 but I am not able to change the Platform Toolset as suggested (where to do that?).

Comment: What version of .NET Framework are you targeting? As far as I know, Windows XP is not supported for 4.5. Can you for the time being target 4.0 instead?

Comment: The Support for XP will only be for native C++ Projects. .NET 4.5 will not be supported on XP. Maybe you can restrict your Project to the .NET 4.0 Framework target.

Comment: I was targetting the .Net 4.5 Framework. I do a test: new VS2012 solution, targetting .Net 4.0 Framework, publish through ClickOnce, copy/paste on usb key, try to install on Win XP computer >> same error: setup.exe is not a valid win32 application.

Comment: Ok finally, I will have to use VS2010 to create my ClickOnce setup files as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319952/how-do-i-target-net-4-0-3-on-xp-using-visual-studio-2012-application-fails-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue, but found a simple fix:
Instead of running the setup.exe run the "xxxxxx.application" file in the same location.
This will execute and install in exactly the same manner and does not complain about not being a 32bit app.

Comment: This won't work because the .application file doesn't check for prerequisites. That's what the setup.exe is for.